# Draw a route on a map (android)

Tags: android, google-maps, routes

Can  i draw three route in my application(use google map api),i can draw a route with kml,
now i want to draw three different route  between two points,such as  foot, bike, bus and so 
on.

Comment: Please be more specific. "Can I draw a route in android" is not the right way to ask a question. Try asking for suggestions on how to get started or if anyone knows of any good resources for doing similar tasks.

Answer (score 1):

```
 String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + lat+","+lon+"&daddr="+lat1+","+lon1;
   Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
   intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
   startActivity(intent);
```

I think this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can draw a route in Android on a map, you may want to start by saving your GPS points into a database.

You could also just use the Google Maps API to do this for you automatically.

Comment: i'm not mean track. i want to mock the goole map in html ,you can choose foot ,bus ,car.it's show you different route.